# how to stop a show() when i hover another div container?

Tags: jquery, html, slider, hide, show

i am trying to make a little div show up inside a wrapper div when its on hover and it all works good but for example if i pass from a wrapper to the wrapper next to it the first little div on the first wrapper stay like stuck i think it is a stop() problem so how can i fix it, thanks.

```
$(function(){
        $(".show-more").hide()
        $(".product-box").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().children(".show-more").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
            })
        $(".product-box").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).stop().children(".show-more").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);    
                })
});
```

the HTML CODE is:

```
<div class="product-box">
<div class="show-more">
</div>
<img src="'.$pic.'" />
<ul>
<li>'.$designiation.'</li>
<li>'.$type.'</li>
<li><strong>'.$variete.'</strong></li>
</ul>
</div>'
```

this html code is inside a php loop.

Comment: Did you try the aptly named [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method with parameters **stop(true, true)**

Comment: can you provide your HTML please..

Comment: see `finish()` method or pass `true` to `stop()` method as suggested by Adeneo. Reading the DOC would help you

Comment: what is a named stop() method? you mean stop(true,true)?

Comment: `hover !== mouseenter`

Comment: @BlackSheep true, here OP is using in/out handler which i guess it is not what he is looking for

Answer (score 1):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eVabAMu/1/edit)

Something like this?

```
$(".product-box").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".show-more").stop().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Remember that hover used as a named method `.hover()` is a way to register both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: seems to be the simplest way to get expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".product-box").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".show-more").stop().slideDown(300);
},function(){
    $(this).find(".show-more").stop().slideUp(300);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EZC2A/)

Read [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup)

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/DDqFm/

```
$(function () {
    $(".show-more").hide();
    $(".product-box").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".show-more").slideDown(300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".show-more").slideUp(300);
    });
});
```